# help with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: password-recovery, username

i have downloaded a copy of Ubuntu 14.04
I put it on to a disk to upload on to my laptop
but once it started to upload  it asked my to make a username and password
to continue once I have done that it keeps telling me that there is no match 
I have never made a username and password before is there anyway pass this 
or is there another download that I can use to sort out my laptop
as I lost my reformatting disks

Comment: It sounds like you're not entering the password correctly, if at all, in the Confirm Password box. Make sure it is exactly the same as you typed in the Pasword box.

Comment: Close-voters: I think this question is clear (and [have answered it](https://askubuntu.com/a/620807/22949)).

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu, you decide what you want your password to be, and *enter it twice*. One of the textboxes asks you to enter your password, and the other asks you to confirm it.

If during that step the installer tells you it doesn't match, which appears to be what you are describing, then [as Zacharee1 says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619814/help-with-ubuntu-14-04#comment875772_619814) this means you did not enter them the same each time.

In this step, you are *creating* a new password for yourself. Your password will be whatever you decide. It is not a problem that you didn't create one before or that you were never given one. Just type exactly the same text in both password boxes, and you should be able to continue with the installation.